# Magento 2 - Jquery not triggering any events for Product attribute input fields in new product form

Tags: magento2, admin, product-attribute, catalog, jquery

I have a product attribute named **stone_weight**. I'm trying to get the value of the attribute based on it's name *`name="product[stone_weight]"`* on change event. But it is not triggering any event. How can i properly use any event like change or keyup.

```
require.config({
        deps: [
            'jquery'
        ],
        callback: function ($) {
            $(document).ready(function(e){
                $('input[name="product\\[stone_weight\\]"]').change(function(e){
                    $stone = $('input[name="product\\[stone_weight\\]"]').val();
                    console.log($stone);
                });
            })
        }
    });
```

Comment: You have used net_weight instead of stone_weight in above code.

Comment: please share your code to get more help

Comment: Sorry. Question edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with below code,

```
 callback: function ($) {
            $(document).ready(function(e){
                $(document).on('change',$('input[name="product[stone_weight]"]'),function(e){
                    $stone = $('input[name="product\\[stone_weight\\]"]').val();
                    console.log($stone);
                });
            })
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It really helped me a lot. Kudos...

Comment: but it's preventing me from saving the value. It is saved as 0.